# Using ~ to make another element change style

Tags: html, css

Sorry for a misleading title, it is pretty hard to describe this problem in few words.

Basically I want it to when I hover over the caption I want the headline for the block to get a text underline.

Right now I have a JSFiddle where it does this on every other caption than the one that I am hovering.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gNFpj/1/

CSS:

```
.caption {
width: 480px;
height: 270px;
float: left;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
}
.caption p {
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
margin-top: -53px;
height: 50px;
padding: 7px;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
opacity: 0.7;
font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 19px;
}
.caption p span {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 14px;
}
.caption:hover ~ .caption p span {
text-decoration: underline;
}
.caption a {
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: So u want the hovered caption get underline - only the hovered?

Answer (score 2):

You want a simple descending selector:

`.caption:hover p span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/gNFpj/2/